# How to use select count on my database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

```
private void Update_table(){    
    try {    
        String sql= "select Firstname, Lastname,ID_number from regmembers";   
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        jTable_regMembers.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));    
        jTable_regMembers.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        jTable_regMembers.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jTable_regMembers.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false); 
    } catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e+"");
    } 
}
```

how can i display the data of registered members of my database and put it into jtextfield, newbie question?

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the resultset object and set the values obtained

```
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next()) {
    do {
        // perform your logic
        yourTextfield.setText(rs.getString("yourColumnName"));
    } while(resultSet.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to execute a simple query and use the value in the Result set to set your textfield.

```
String sql = "Select count(*) from regmembers";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
textfield.setText(rs.getInt(1));
```

Hope this works the way you wanted it to

Comment: Your title is a little misleading. For each column you can use rs.getString("columnName") or rs.getInt("columnName") depending on the column type. So rs.getString("FirstName") etc